# WSO2 API Manager - Error changing admin password

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I have 2 Stores, 2 Publihser, 2 Gateway Workers, 1 Gateway Manager working with a SVN Synchronizer.

When I'm using default user and passaword (admin:admin) everething works weel.
But When I change using [1], and I try publish a API, I receve this error:

```
TID[-1234] [AM] [2016-07-15 15:45:29,735] INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = /
```

At Publisher node shows "Sample API is Deploying" forever.

Comment: Have you changed the values of admin/admin in the api-manager.xml file of each component (gateway, Key Manager, etc.)?

Comment: Yes,  I did. I changed it in all nodes.

Comment: Do all the nodes pointed to the same userstore database? When you try to publish an api, what are the error logs you see in publisher and gateway manager node?