# Error changing admin password wso2am-2.0.0 new install

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I've changed the wso2carbon.jks keystore to my own store and my CA signed cert is working fine via a remote browser for https. However when I try to change the admin password via the carbon management console UI and restart the API manager I get problems with:

AMQConnection Unable to connect to broker at tcp://10.16.0.5:5673
org.wso2.andes.AMQException: Error occurred while establishing a connection

I'm running 2.0.0 of API manager on Ubuntu 14.04

I don't have enough points to comment on a similar issue:

[WSO2 API Manager - Error changing admin password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38403667/wso2-api-manager-error-changing-admin-password)

but happy to experiment and isolate this bug. I could try to change the admin password for all references in xml files under conf if needed.
Please advise on the best way to change the admin password for API manager. I'm happy to do a clean install and see if I can just change the admin password. Please advise if I should use the UI or change in repository/conf files.

Comment: following these exact instructions from ws02 I was able the change the password successfully. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Maintaining+Logins+and+Passwords

Answer (score 0):

Search all xml files with "admin" references. What I can recall is, api-manager.xml, user-mgt.xml, identity.xml, etc.. You may also check out [the related wso2 doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Maintaining+Logins+and+Passwords).

Answer (score 0):

I've just worked through this issue with WSO2 support.  In my case it had to do with the content of the password.  I used the same admin password for v2 as I did for v1.10 but apparently the different frameworks in v2 has a problem with special characters in the password.  More specifically, a '@' character.  The link below was provided as a reference.  Upon changing the admin password, both in the console and in the user-mgt.xml file, and restarting the product, I am no longer experiencing the exception.

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-4991